# knockout.js data-bind 'with' conflicts with jQuery change event

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, onchange

For some reason, when I use the data-bind="with: detailedStudent" the jQuery change() binding does not get called.  I'm dynamically populating the select options but I'm not sure that should matter.  This is some of the code I'm using just to try to give a decent picture of what's going on:

```
var viewModel;
$(document).ready(function() {  
    viewModel = new StudentViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 

    // this change event is not getting called, but if i put the onchange directly into the html as an attribute, it works fine.
    $("#accountDialog").find("#mySelect").change(function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
}

function Student(data) {
    var self = this;    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);                
}

function StudentViewModel() {
    var self = this;    
    this.students = ko.observableArray([]);    
    this.detailedStudent = ko.observable(); 
}

<div id="accountDialog" class="modal hide fade" data-bind="with: detailedStudent">
    <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" data-bind="value: GraduationClassId"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `with` binding is a wrapper to the `template` binding.  It copies off the child elements and uses them as the template.  So, if your `detailedStudent` is changing, then KO will be rendering new elements each time that did not have the event handler attached to it.

Some alternatives:

- use a binding to attach the event handler (can use `event` binding)
- create a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) against your `detailedStudent` observable and perform your action in the view model (best option, if your action does not involve DOM manipulation)
- try to use a delegated event handler like jQuerys `$.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: Yep, this did it... here's what I added: this.GraduationClass.GraduationClassId.subscribe(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });

Answer (score 0):

If the action does not involve DOM manipulation, then I agree with RP Niemeyer, the manual subscription is the best option.

However, usually we will have some event with DOM manipulation, for example, to setup the jquery dialog / datepicker plugin to your property. I regard the custom binding would be the best option. The custom binding will work perfectly with the "with" binding clause to setup event handlers to arbitary javascript function.

You could read through this and it is not as hard as it seems to be.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html